# Do I need a Proxy Setup on Home Router?

Tags: proxy

I have a small networking setup around a Netgear WNR3500L (using TomatoUSB).
I use the router for VPN, wireless, media server and Samba shares. I have a desktop, a laptop and few handhelds.

Will it help if there is a Squid Proxy (Do I need one ?)? My ISP bandwidth is 1024kbps up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly not - Proxy's are only really useful for enterprises who want to authenticate/block/monitor internet connections.  The caching effects of proxies are nowadays really minimal - most ISPs who once transparently proxied content for caching are removing them.

The most effective caching for speeding up your web browsing will be done automatically by your web browser.